# App Engine (python) skips webapp middleware (like Appstats) in production but works fine on dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, middleware, appstats

I'm using App Engine python to host an application and would love to use Appstats and a couple of other libraries that run as middleware.  However, when I set up middleware through appengine_config.py (as shown below) it works on the dev server but not in production.  Appstats AND gaesessions work like a charm in the dev server and don't work at all in production.  Here is my appengine_config.py, located in my root /src dir:

```
from com.impactpy.gaesessions import SessionMiddleware 
COOKIE_KEY = 'nice try' 
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app): 
    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording 
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key=COOKIE_KEY) 
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app) 
    return app
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

So I'm bringing this back up as I've tried again to fix it to no avail.  I've boiled appengine_config.py down to:

```
from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```

and app.yaml includes

```
builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
- remote_api: on
- appstats: on
```

My app uses basic webapp, bottom of every request-handling file includes:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [
    ('/handler', myHandlerClass)
    ],debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Deploying works fine.  App has been going strong for over a year and sees lots of requests.  myapp.appspot.com/_ah/stats comes up showing the GUI with a refresh button, no data, and the message "No requests have been recorded yet" etc.  I'm confused!

Comment: Is it throwing any exception in prod? Is the code for `com.impactpy.gaesessions.SessionMiddleware` actually sent to prod?

Comment: Can you add the code for your request handler?

Comment: The code is sent to prod, yes (at least everything else in the directory is).  I have dozens of request handlers that utilize sessions, so pasting them would be hard...

But lets focus on Appstats.  It works on the dev server (I set it up in app.yaml for /stats) just fine.  When I log in as an admin and visit /stats in production, I can actually see the GUI for appstats but it is completely empty (no data).  Appstats middleware simply doesn't run, and it should insert itself for any request without further code on my part (as it does on the dev server).  Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Are you using a google apps for your own domain account or a gmail.com account?  This was an issue at one point, not sure of its current status.

Comment: bringing this back up with my edits above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is how you import SessionMiddleware. Try to put gaesessions at the top level of your project directory.

Here is an `appengine_config.py` I used successfully:

```
from gaesessions import SessionMiddleware
from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key="s3cr3t")
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```

Comment: You're right - problem was the location of gaesessions module (I had it nested in my package structure, and it needed to be top level.  HOWEVER - appstats is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a continuous deployment pipeline setup and forgot to commit and push the `appengine_config.py` file. Double check that that file is available.

Furthermore, to further configure the appstats module, refer to the file that is available in the appengine sdk source code:

`/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/appstats/sample_appengine_config.py`

This is it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#




"""Sample Appstats Configuration.

There are four sections:

0) WSGI middleware declaration.
1) Django version declaration.
2) Configuration constants.
3) Configuration functions.

Also a section at the end for the remote_api handler.

"""



import logging
import os
import random
import re

# 0) WSGI middleware declaration.

# Only use this if you're not Django; with Django, it's easier to add
#   'google.appengine.ext.appstats.recording.AppstatsDjangoMiddleware',
# to your Django settings.py file.

# # def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
# #   from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
# #   app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
# #   return app


# 1) Django version declaration.

# If your application uses Django and requires a specific version of
# Django, uncomment the following block of three lines.  Currently
# supported values for the Django version are '0.96' (the default),
# '1.0', and '1.1'.

# # from google.appengine.dist import use_library
# # use_library('django', '1.0')
# # import django


# 2) Configuration constants.

# DEBUG: True or False.  When True, verbose messages are logged at the
# DEBUG level.  Also, this flag is causes tracebacks to be shown in
# the web UI when an exception occurs.  (Tracebacks are always logged
# at the ERROR level as well.)

appstats_DEBUG = False

# DUMP_LEVEL: -1, 0, 1 or 2.  Controls how much debug output is
# written to the logs by the internal dump() function during event
# recording.  -1 dumps nothing; 0 dumps one line of information; 1
# dumps more informat and 2 dumps the maximum amount of information.
# You would only need to change this if you were debugging the
# recording implementation.

appstats_DUMP_LEVEL = -1

# SHELL_OK: True or False.  Defaults to True in SDK, False in production.
# If True, /_ah/stats/shell brings up a UI where you can run arbitrary
# Python code.  This is like /_ah/admin/interactive, but also displays
# full Appstats details about the code you ran.

appstats_SHELL_OK = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Dev')

# DEFAULT_SCRIPT: Default script for shell window.
appstats_DEFAULT_SCRIPT = "print 'Hello, world.'"

# The following constants control the resolution and range of the
# memcache keys used to record information about individual requests.
# Two requests that are closer than KEY_DISTANCE milliseconds will be
# mapped to the same key (thus losing all information about the
# earlier of the two requests).  Up to KEY_MODULUS distinct keys are
# generated; after KEY_DISTANCE * KEY_MODULUS milliseconds the key
# values roll over.  Increasing KEY_MODULUS causes a proportional
# increase of the amount of data saved in memcache.  Increasing
# KEY_DISTANCE causes a requests during a larger timespan to be
# recorded, at the cost of increasing risk of assigning the same key
# to two adjacent requests.

appstats_KEY_DISTANCE = 100
appstats_KEY_MODULUS = 1000

# The following constants control the namespace and key values used to
# store information in memcache.  You can safely leave this alone.

appstats_KEY_NAMESPACE = '__appstats__'
appstats_KEY_PREFIX = '__appstats__'
appstats_KEY_TEMPLATE = ':%06d'
appstats_PART_SUFFIX = ':part'
appstats_FULL_SUFFIX = ':full'
appstats_LOCK_SUFFIX = '<lock>'

# Numerical limits on how much information is saved for each event.
# MAX_STACK limits the number of stack frames saved; MAX_LOCALS limits
# the number of local variables saved per stack frame.  MAX_REPR
# limits the length of the string representation of each variable
# saved; MAX_DEPTH limits the nesting depth used when computing the
# string representation of structured variables (e.g. lists of lists).

appstats_MAX_STACK = 10
appstats_MAX_LOCALS = 10
appstats_MAX_REPR = 100
appstats_MAX_DEPTH = 10

# Regular expressions.  These are matched against the 'code key' of a
# stack frame, which is a string of the form
# '<filename>:<function>:<lineno>'.  If the code key of a stack frame
# matches RE_STACK_BOTTOM, it and all remaining stack frames are
# skipped.  If the code key matches RE_STACK_SKIP, that frame is not
# saved but subsequent frames may be saved.

appstats_RE_STACK_BOTTOM = r'dev_appserver\.py'
appstats_RE_STACK_SKIP = r'recording\.py|apiproxy_stub_map\.py'

# Timeout for memcache lock management, in seconds.

appstats_LOCK_TIMEOUT = 1

# Timezone offset.  This is used to convert recorded times (which are
# all in UTC) to local time.  The default is US/Pacific winter time.

appstats_TZOFFSET = 8*3600

# URL path (sans host) leading to the stats UI.  Should match app.yaml.
# If "builtins: - appstats: on" is used, the path should be /_ah/stats.

appstats_stats_url = '/_ah/stats'

# Fraction of requests to record.  Set this to a float between 0.0
# and 1.0 to record that fraction of all requests.

appstats_RECORD_FRACTION = 1.0

# List of dicts mapping env vars to regular expressions.  Each dict
# specifies a set of filters to be 'and'ed together.  The keys are
# environment variables, the values are *match* regular expressions.
# A request is recorded if it matches all filters of at least one
# dict.  If the FILTER_LIST variable is empty, all requests are
# recorded.  Missing environment variables are considered to have
# the empty string as value.  If a regular expression starts with
# '!', the sense of the match is negated (the value should *not*
# match the expression).

appstats_FILTER_LIST = []

# DATASTORE_DETAILS: True or False. This is an experimental flag
# and is not guaranteed to be supported or work the same way in the
# future. When True, information regarding keys of entities read or
# written during various datastore operations and other related details
# are recorded. Currently the information is logged for the following
# datastore calls: Get, Put, RunQuery and Next.

appstats_DATASTORE_DETAILS = False

# CALC_RPC_COSTS: True or False. This is an experimental flag
# and is not guaranteed to be supported or work the same way in the
# future. When True, the cost and billed operations for each RPC are
# recorded and displayed in the AppStats UI. Turning this option on
# may negatively impact application performance.

appstats_CALC_RPC_COSTS = False

# 3) Configuration functions.

# should_record() can be used to record a random percentage of calls.
# The argument is the CGI or WSGI environment dict.  The default
# implementation returns True iff the request matches FILTER_LIST (see
# above) *and* random.random() < RECORD_FRACTION.

def appstats_should_record(env):
  if appstats_FILTER_LIST:
    logging.debug('FILTER_LIST: %r', appstats_FILTER_LIST)
    for filter_dict in appstats_FILTER_LIST:
      for key, regex in filter_dict.iteritems():
        negated = isinstance(regex, str) and regex.startswith('!')
        if negated:
          regex = regex[1:]
        value = env.get(key, '')
        if bool(re.match(regex, value)) == negated:
          logging.debug('No match on %r for %s=%r', regex, key, value)
          break
      else:
        logging.debug('Match on %r', filter_dict)
        break
    else:
      logging.debug('Non-empty FILTER_LIST, but no filter matches')
      return False
  if appstats_RECORD_FRACTION >= 1.0:
    return True
  return random.random() < appstats_RECORD_FRACTION

# The following functions are called by the UI code only; they don't
# affect the recorded information.

# normalize_path() takes a path and returns an 'path key'.  The path
# key is used by the UI to compute statistics for similar URLs.  If
# your application has a large or infinite URL space (e.g. each issue
# in an issue tracker might have its own numeric URL), this function
# can be used to produce more meaningful statistics.

def appstats_normalize_path(path):
  return path

# extract_key() is a lower-level function with the same purpose as
# normalize_key().  It can be used to lump different request methods
# (e.g. GET and POST) together, or conversely to use other information
# on the request object (mostly the query string) to produce a more
# fine-grained path key.  The argument is a StatsProto object; this is
# a class defined in recording.py.  Useful methods are:

#   - http_method()
#   - http_path()
#   - http_query()
#   - http_status()

# Note that the StatsProto argument is loaded only with summary
# information; this means you cannot access the request headers.

def appstats_extract_key(request):
  key = appstats_normalize_path(request.http_path())
  if request.http_method() != 'GET':
    key = '%s %s' % (request.http_method(), key)
  return key


# ########################################
# Remote_API Authentication configuration.

# See google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py for more information.
# In most cases, you will not want to configure this.

# remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = (
#     'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID', ['a trusted appid here'])
```