# Cannot access AppStats on deployed version

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

I have enabled appstats for my Python App Engine application, and I can access it locally under the /_ah/stats/ url but when I deploy the application and visit the appspot.com under my application in the UI there is no custom AppStats link as it should have. In my yaml file I define:

```
builtins:
- appstats: on
```

I wrap my application in `appengine_config.py` like this:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
  app = SessionMiddleware(app, cookie_key="MyRandomString")
  app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
  return app
```

I used this configuration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349147/app-engine-python-skips-webapp-middleware-like-appstats-in-production-but-wo).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There shouldn't be a link in the managment site (unless you add it using [admin_console](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Administration_Console_Custom_Pages)).
The stats should be available at your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/stats